# Compact set in open connected set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $K$ be connected open set and $cl(K)$ compact such that $cl(K)\subseteq D$ where $D$ connected open set in set of complex numbers and $Bd(K)$ is a continuous curve.

Will it imply: $Bd(K)$ is homotopic to a point in $D$.

Question arise from: Understanding Rouche theorem statement given on wiki 
[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouché%27s_theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem)

Proof uses Argument principle but argumen principle is true for curves homotopic to a point.

Question 2: As example given by M. Winter, this is not true if $Bd(K)$ is simply image of a continuous loop. What if it is image of 1-1 continuous loop i.e. homeomorphic to $S^1$ i.e. image of simple loop.

Comment: I assume $K^o$, $K^0$ and $K$ are the same set, right? Please check your notation then. With $\mathrm{Bd}(K)$ being a continuous curve, I assume you mean that there is a continuous function $f:S^1\to \Bbb C$ so that $\mathrm{im}(f)=\mathrm{Bd}(K)$. Is this correct? Do you also assume that $f$ is injective?

Comment: ya sorry will edit it.

Comment: @M.Winter edited question also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680441/inside-of-boundary-of-an-open-region. I will be done in this question if I can prove that $R^2\setminus$ is connected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general, depending on your exact definitions. Consider the following figure:

[image]

The (interior of the) lighter area is $D$, the (interior of the) darker area is $K$. The boundary of $K$ can be considered the embedding of a closed curve which winds around the annulus twice, henc cannot be contracted to a point in $D$.

Comment: now your example also makes me think that if $D$ open connected and $Bd(D)$ simple loop homopotic to point. Will it imply $R^2\setminus cl(D)$ connected?

Comment: what if I impose condition that $Bd(K)$ is image of a simple loop.